# Plugin settings page radio button not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I'm having trouble with a plugin I'm working on, in the plugin admin area, there should be radio buttons for the user to choose between test mode or live mode
the problem is when the user chooses live mode and clicks save, the page refresh and the radio button go back to test mode

here is the code

```
 <?php

class GpgBookingAdmin {


     /**
     * Holds the values to be used in the fields callbacks
     */
    private $options;

    /**
     * Start up
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'add_plugin_page' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'page_init' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Add options page
     */
    public function add_plugin_page()
    {
        // This page will be under "Settings"
        add_options_page(
            'Settings Admin',
            'Gpg Setting',
            'manage_options',
            'gpg-setting-admin',
            array( $this, 'create_admin_page' )
        );
    }

    /**
     * Options page callback
     */
    public function create_admin_page()
    {
        // Set class property
        $this->options = get_option( 'gpg_option_name' );
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h1>My Settings</h1>
            <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php
                // This prints out all hidden setting fields
                settings_fields( 'gpg_option_group' );
                do_settings_sections( 'gpg-setting-admin' );
                submit_button();
            ?>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    /**
     * Register and add settings
     */
    public function page_init()
    {
        register_setting(
            'gpg_option_group', // Option group
            'gpg_option_name', // Option name
            array( $this, 'sanitize' ) // Sanitize
        );

        add_settings_section(
            'setting_section_id', // ID
            'Gpg Custom Settings', // Title
            array( $this, 'print_section_info' ), // Callback
            'gpg-setting-admin' // Page
        );

        add_settings_field(
            'gpg_golf_apikey',
            'Golf API key',
            array( $this, 'gpg_golf_apikey' ),
            'gpg-setting-admin',
            'setting_section_id'
        );

        add_settings_field(
            'gpg_api_mode',
            'Golf API Mode',
            array( $this, 'gpg_api_mode' ),
            'gpg-setting-admin',
            'setting_section_id'
        );

        add_settings_field(
            'gpg_strip_publishkey', // ID
            'Strip PublishKey', // Title
            array( $this, 'gpg_strip_publishkey' ), // Callback
            'gpg-setting-admin', // Page
            'setting_section_id' // Section
        );

        add_settings_field(
            'gpg_strip_secretkey',
            'Strip Secret key',
            array( $this, 'gpg_strip_secretkey' ),
            'gpg-setting-admin',
            'setting_section_id'
        );


    }

    /**
     * Sanitize each setting field as needed
     *
     * @param array $input Contains all settings fields as array keys
     */
    public function sanitize( $input )
    {
       // $new_input = array();

        return $input;
    }

    /**
     * Print the Section text
     */
    public function print_section_info()
    {
        print 'Enter your settings below:';
    }

    /**
     * Get the settings option array and print one of its values
     */
    public function gpg_golf_apikey()
    {
        printf(
            '<input type="text" id="gpg_golf_apikey" name="gpg_option_name[gpg_golf_apikey]" value="%s" />',
            isset( $this->options['gpg_golf_apikey'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->options['gpg_golf_apikey']) : ''
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the settings option array and print one of its values
     */
    public function gpg_api_mode()
    {
        printf(
            '<input type="radio" name="gpg_option_name[gpg_api_mode]" value="0" checked /> Test
<input type="radio" name="gpg_option_name[gpg_api_mode]" value="1" /> Live',
            isset( $this->options['gpg_api_mode'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->options['gpg_api_mode']) : ''
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the settings option array and print one of its values
     */
    public function gpg_strip_publishkey()
    {
        printf(
            '<input type="text" id="gpg_strip_publishkey" name="gpg_option_name[gpg_strip_publishkey]" value="%s" />',
            isset( $this->options['gpg_strip_publishkey'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->options['gpg_strip_publishkey']) : ''
        );
    }

    public function gpg_strip_secretkey()
    {
        printf(
            '<input type="text" id="gpg_strip_secretkey" name="gpg_option_name[gpg_strip_secretkey]" value="%s" />',
            isset( $this->options['gpg_strip_secretkey'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->options['gpg_strip_secretkey']) : ''
        );
    }
}





function add_theme_menu_item()
{
 add_menu_page("Golf Settings", "Golf Settings", "manage_options", "golf-settings-panel", "golfSettingsPage", null, 99);
}

add_action("admin_menu", "add_theme_menu_item");

function golfSettingsPage()
{
    ?>
     <div class="wrap">
     <h1>Golf Settings</h1> <!-- page title is added from here -->
     <form method="post" action="options.php">
         <?php
             settings_fields("section");
             do_settings_sections("theme-options");
             submit_button();
         ?>
     </form>
  </div>
 <?php
}


add_action("admin_init", "display_theme_panel_fields");
function display_theme_panel_fields()
{
 add_settings_section("section", "<hr/>", null, "theme-options");


 add_settings_field("teeTimePage", "Select Tee Time Results", "selectTeeTimePage", "theme-options", "section");
 register_setting("section", "teeTimePage");

 add_settings_field("search_result_page", "Select Search Result Page", "selectPage", "theme-options", "section");
 register_setting("section", "search_result_page");

 add_settings_field("bookingPage", "Select Booking Page", "selectBookingPage", "theme-options", "section");
 register_setting("section", "bookingPage");

 add_settings_field("bookingConfirmationPage", "Select Booking Page", "selectBookingConfirmationPagePage", "theme-options", "section");
 register_setting("section", "bookingConfirmationPage");

 /*add_settings_field("bookingConfirmationPage", "Select Booking Page", "selectBookingConfirmationPagePage", "theme-options", "section");
 register_setting("section", "bookingConfirmationPage");
*/

}



function selectBookingPage()
{
    $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'page',
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'order'=>'desc',
   'posts_per_page' =>-1
   );
 $new_query = new WP_Query( $args );
 $totalPages = array();

 echo '<select name="bookingPage" id="bookingPage" >';
  while ( $new_query->have_posts() ) : $new_query->the_post();
   $savedOption = get_option('bookingPage');
   $currentID = get_the_ID();

   if($savedOption == $currentID) {
    $select = 'selected';
   }else{
    $select = '';
   }

   echo '<option '.$select.' value='.$currentID.'>'.get_the_title($currentID).'</option>';
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_query();
 echo '</select>';

}

function selectBookingConfirmationPagePage()
{
    $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'page',
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'order'=>'desc',
   'posts_per_page' =>-1
   );
 $new_query = new WP_Query( $args );
 $totalPages = array();

 echo '<select name="bookingConfirmationPage" id="bookingConfirmationPage" >';
  while ( $new_query->have_posts() ) : $new_query->the_post();
   $savedOption = get_option('bookingConfirmationPage');
   $currentID = get_the_ID();

   if($savedOption == $currentID) {
    $select = 'selected';
   }else{
    $select = '';
   }

   echo '<option '.$select.' value='.$currentID.'>'.get_the_title($currentID).'</option>';
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_query();
 echo '</select>';

}
function selectTeeTimePage()
{
    $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'page',
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'order'=>'desc',
   'posts_per_page' =>-1
   );
 $new_query = new WP_Query( $args );
 $totalPages = array();

 echo '<select name="teeTimePage" id="teeTimePage" >';
  while ( $new_query->have_posts() ) : $new_query->the_post();
   $savedOption = get_option('teeTimePage');
   $currentID = get_the_ID();

   if($savedOption == $currentID) {
    $select = 'selected';
   }else{
    $select = '';
   }

   echo '<option '.$select.' value='.$currentID.'>'.get_the_title($currentID).'</option>';
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_query();
 echo '</select>';

}

function selectPage()
{

 $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'page',
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'order'=>'desc',
   'posts_per_page' =>-1
   );
 $new_query = new WP_Query( $args );
 $totalPages = array();

 echo '<select name="search_result_page" id="search_result_page" >';
  while ( $new_query->have_posts() ) : $new_query->the_post();
   $savedOption = get_option('search_result_page');
   $currentID = get_the_ID();

   if($savedOption == $currentID) {
    $select = 'selected';
   }else{
    $select = '';
   }

   echo '<option '.$select.' value='.$currentID.'>'.get_the_title($currentID).'</option>';
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_query();
 echo '</select>';
}
```

here is the radio button lines

```
 public function gpg_api_mode()
    {
        printf(
            '<input type="radio" name="gpg_option_name[gpg_api_mode]" value="0" checked /> Test
<input type="radio" name="gpg_option_name[gpg_api_mode]" value="1" /> Live',
            isset( $this->options['gpg_api_mode'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->options['gpg_api_mode']) : ''
        );
    }
```

also, I'm trying to make the button choice trigger a php function based on the user choice
for example test mode checked, then always use function1
live mode on then always use function2

here is the 2 functions it calls

```
 public static function http_post($apiName = "courses", $post = array(), $customRequest = "")
        {
            $postString = "";
            //https://www.golf18network.com/apiv2
            //https://www.golf18staging=.com/apiv2/$apiName
            $url        = "https://www.golf18staging.com/apiv2/$apiName";
            $ch         = curl_init();


            $headers    = array();
            $headers[]  = 'X-API-KEY:' . GPGBOOKING_GET_API_KEY;

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

            if ($post)
            {
                foreach ($post as $key => $value)
                {
                    $postString .= $key . "=" . $value . "&";
                }

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString);
            }

            if ($customRequest)
            {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
            }

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

            $simplifiedResponse = curl_exec($ch);
            $error               = curl_error($ch);

            $simplifiedResponse = json_decode($simplifiedResponse);

            curl_close($ch);

            /*echo "<pre>";
            print_r($simplifiedResponse);
            print_r($error);
    */

            return $simplifiedResponse;
        }

and the second funtion is


    public static function http_post($apiName = "courses", $post = array(), $customRequest = "")
        {
            $postString = "";
            //https://www.golf18network.com/apiv2
            //https://www.golf18staging=.com/apiv2/$apiName
            $url        = "https://www.golf18network.com/apiv2/$apiName";
            $ch         = curl_init();


            $headers    = array();
            $headers[]  = 'X-API-KEY:' . GPGBOOKING_GET_API_KEY;

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

            if ($post)
            {
                foreach ($post as $key => $value)
                {
                    $postString .= $key . "=" . $value . "&";
                }

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString);
            }

            if ($customRequest)
            {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
            }

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

            $simplifiedResponse = curl_exec($ch);
            $error               = curl_error($ch);



$simplifiedResponse = json_decode($simplifiedResponse);

        curl_close($ch);

        /*echo "<pre>";
        print_r($simplifiedResponse);
        print_r($error);
*/

        return $simplifiedResponse;
    }
```

Last thing, I've tried solving the radio button selection issue using this code,

```
 public function gpg_api_mode()
    {
        printf(
            '<%
String whichRadio = request.getParameter("gpg_option_name[gpg_api_mode]");
String r1checked = "";
if (whichRadio.equals("1")) r1checked = " checked";
String r2checked = "";
if (whichRadio.equals("2")) r2checked = " checked";
%>

            <input type="radio" name="gpg_option_name[gpg_api_mode]" value="1"<%= r1Checked %>/> Test
<input type="radio" name="gpg_option_name[gpg_api_mode]" value="2" <%= r2Checked %>/> Live',
            isset( $this->options['gpg_api_mode'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->options['gpg_api_mode']) : ''
        );
    }
```

but I'm getting error 
Warning: printf(): Too few arguments in class.gpgBookingAdmin.php on line 15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for solving the `radio` selection issue:

```
    /**
     * Get the settings option array and print one of its values
     */
    public function gpg_api_mode()
    {
        $value = isset( $this->options['gpg_api_mode'] ) ? $this->options['gpg_api_mode'] : '0';
        printf(
            '<input type="radio" name="gpg_option_name[gpg_api_mode]" value="0"%s /> Test
<input type="radio" name="gpg_option_name[gpg_api_mode]" value="1"%s /> Live',
            checked( '0', $value, false ), // "checked" attr when API mode is "Test"
            checked( '1', $value, false ) // "checked" attr when API mode is "Live"
        );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Sally, that worked perfectly, thanks a lot, I hope I can fix other problems as well

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure if I understand the other problems. First, do you want to call the `http_post()` function from within `GpgBookingAdmin::gpg_api_mode()`? Secondly, in what `class` does the function (i.e. `http_post()`) belongs to?

Comment: the other problem is located in these lines ' public static function http_post($apiName = "courses", $post = array(), $customRequest = "")
        {
            $postString = "";
            //https://www.golf18network.com/apiv2
            //https://www.golf18staging=.com/apiv2/$apiName
            $url        = "https://www.golf18staging.com/apiv2/$apiName";
            $ch         = curl_init(); '
I'm trying to get the value from the radio button to switch $url depending which is located in another php file